# Stable Firebase packages for Flutter when adding firebase_database

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dependencies, flutter-dependencies

Throughout my flutter development I have had numerous issues with Firebase plugins not cooperating with each other, and have had quite some difficulty narrowing down which versions of packages are compatible. I've recently added firebase_database and cannot seem to find a stable configuration that allows me to actually use a realtime connection without crashing my app.

If anyone could share a similar setup they've used and can confirm is stable, it would greatly help me narrow down possibilities of what is going wrong.

Here is the relevant portion of my pubspec.yaml:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  firebase_core: ^2.1.0
  firebase_auth: ^4.0.0
  cloud_firestore: ^4.9.0
  firebase_database: ^10.2.7
  firebase_analytics: ^10.0.0
  cloud_functions: ^4.0.0
  #firebase_messaging will be needed eventually, but not now.
```

A long time ago I found a page that directly listed which versions are meant to be used together but have not been able to find it again in over a year. If it still exists could someone send me a link? I would like to solve the firebase dependency issue more permanently since it is a recurring issue for me.

As a secondary question, this is the relevant portion of my app that is causing a crash. I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out what is wrong since any time I listen to it my app crashes immediately, but it seems to have something to do with returning any property of _dbRef.

```
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';

class RealtimeService {
  final DatabaseReference _dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();

  String encodeFirebaseKey(String key) {
    return Uri.encodeComponent(key);
  }

  String decodeFirebaseKey(String encodedKey) {
    return Uri.decodeComponent(encodedKey);
  }

  Stream<Map<String, Conversation>> getConversationsStream(String userEmail) {

    // Check for null _dbRef
    if (_dbRef == null) {
      print('Error: _dbRef is null');
      return Stream.error('Database reference is null');
    }

    String encodedEmail = encodeFirebaseKey(userEmail);

    // Listen for values and handle potential errors inside asyncMap
    return _dbRef
        .child('userConversations')
        .child(encodedEmail)
        .onValue
        .asyncMap((event) async {
          print('mark 1');
      try {
        print('mark 2');

        Map<String, dynamic> userConvos = event.snapshot.value as Map<
            String,
            dynamic> ?? {};

        if (userConvos.isEmpty) {
          return {}; // Return empty map if no conversations found
        }

        // Fetching details of each conversation and mapping it to a list
        Map<String, Conversation> conversations = {};

        await Future.wait(userConvos.keys.map((convoId) async {
          DataSnapshot convoSnapshot = (await _dbRef.child('conversations')
              .child(convoId)
              .once()).snapshot;
          if (convoSnapshot.value != null) {
            conversations[convoId] = ConversationObject.fromMap(
                map: convoSnapshot.value as Map<String, dynamic>);
          }
        }));

        return conversations;
      } catch (e) {
        print('Error in asyncMap: $e');
        throw e;
      }
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to trace the issue. The `Uri.encodeComponent()` method does not by default escape the period `.` character because it's considered a safe character in URI components. However, since Firebase Realtime Database keys do not allow periods, I adjusted my encoding functions to handle periods directly.

```
String encodeFirebaseKey(String key) {
  return Uri.encodeComponent(key).replaceAll('.', '%2E');
  }

String decodeFirebaseKey(String encodedKey) {
    return Uri.decodeComponent(encodedKey.replaceAll('%2E', '.'));
  }
```

So for anyone out there trying to find compatible versions of firebase, the pubspec listed in my original question is a valid configuration.

Still looking for a more robust way to narrow down which packages are compatible though.